# Rest assured - Invalid JSON expression: Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '['

Tags: rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'm trying to retrieve the id of the workflow having "type":"system" using JSON expression

Method:

```
public static int getSystemWorkflowId(final Map<String, String> cookies) {
        return workflow.get(cookies).then().extract().jsonPath().getInt("$..workflows[?(@.type =='system')].id");
    }
```

Payload

```
{
    "workflows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Recruitment workflow",
            "type": "system",
            "options": [
                
            ],
            "active": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "TestWorkflow",
            "options": [
                
            ],
            "active": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
> Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '[' @ line 1, column 39.
> $..workflows[?(@.type =='system')].id

I've tested the expression in an online evaluator and it seems to work...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvD7w.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonPath in Rest-Assured is not [JsonPath Jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), please don't get confused.

JsonPath in Rest-Assured utilizes GPath groovy to find and extract value.

The correct expression would be:

```
.getInt("workflows.find {it.type == 'system'}.id")
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!
Anyway, Do you maybe know if there is some online evaluator for GPath expressions? I found quite a few for JsonPath, but only one for GPath, tthat doesn't even seem to work... It seems that JsonPath if far more popular that GPath :)

Comment: If you need JsonPath then add this dependency to your project, no strict to stick with GPath, I use both in my project.